# FIX or REPLACE: User profile page does not redirect to the requested page after forced password reset

Tags: joomla-3.x, redirect, account-password

I work on a custom Joomla! 3.x module. After registration, users would access my module by clicking a link in an email. I force users to change password at first login, so when they click the link, they are taken to the Edit Your Profile (user-profile) page. Unfortunately after submitting their new password this page does not redirect them to the page that was included in the link in the email. So the process breaks down.

**Here is the list of urls:**

https://dev.gonativeguide.com/de/backoffice/guide-contract?gid=968 (user klicks this to see his document in the custom module)

https://dev.gonativeguide.com/de/component/users/?view=login&Itemid=214 (user logs in on this page with initial password)

https://dev.gonativeguide.com/de/help/user-profile/profile?layout=edit (user gets redirected to this page after login to change this password)

https://dev.gonativeguide.com/de/help/user-profile/profile (when new password is submitted, process stops on this page, no redirect to the guide-contract page in the first URL)

How could I fix this and make sure that the user profile page does redirect to the requested page?

Or would it be easier to write a custom module to replace the user profile page for forced password changes?

Thanks a lot, 
W.

Comment: i recommend you creating a custom module. It's easy and fast.

Comment: I mean, if it's minor changes, you can easy create a custom module for that, otherwise the best way is to override and add your piece of code.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea on how I can "tell" Joomla that I'd like to use my custom module instead of the built in user profile component when users are forced to change their password at first login?

Comment: They reset the password after they log in, right? I need the link of the password change page - full path  -  also the link you want the users to be redirect to.

Comment: I added the list of urls to the post (with bold), please let me know, if you can suggest a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Joomla often sets the URL you want to get to (after the diversion of entering usr/pwd) as a parameter in the URL &return=xxx, where xxx in the base64 encoded URL. After the login stuff is finished Joomla decodes the 'return' URL parameter and sets up an http redirect to it. Don't know if it will work in your case, but would be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I'm not sure I understand fully to implement it. Can you please be a bit more specific to my example and / or provide some further details, information? Thanks!

Comment: Go to eg https://www.base64encode.org/ and enter the URL you want to get to after doing the user stuff. It will then display the base64 encoded equivalent. So for your URL https://dev.gonativeguide.com/de/backoffice/guide-contract?gid=968 it gave me aHR0cHM6Ly9kZXYuZ29uYXRpdmVndWlkZS5jb20vZGUvYmFja29mZmljZS9ndWlkZS1jb250cmFjdD9naWQ9OTY4. Copy that and add it to the URL (which you send in the user email) as a URL parameter where the key is "return", ie &return=aHR0cHM6Ly9kZXYuZ29uYXRpdmVndWlkZS5jb20vZGUvYmFja29mZmljZS9ndWlkZS1jb250cmFjdD9naWQ9OTY4   This may or may not work!